# How to get multiple checked checkbox ID and VALUE at the same time

Tags: php, html, post, checkbox

How to get by POST multiple checked checkbox IDs and VALUEs at the same time? Code bellow shows html to send data.

```
<form action="" method="post">
  first<input type="checkbox" name="first[]" id="first'<?php echo $data; ?>'" value="first" />
  second<input type="checkbox" name="first[]" id="second'<?php echo $data2; ?>'" value="second" />
  third<input type="checkbox" name="first[]" id="third'<?php echo $data3; ?>'" value="third" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

After send by post I get values, but ID is missing.

```
foreach($_POST['first'] as $value){
  echo 'VALUE: '.$value.'<br/>';
}
```

How can I send ID and VALUE and get them by post without explode them? For sure i can split them after, but there should be another way.

Comment: The `id` isn't sent to the server.  What are you actually trying to achieve here and why?

Comment: An element's ID is not transmitted to the back-end. You would have to add a dedicated `<input type="hidden">` and set its value to the value of the ID.

Comment: If id is the same as value - what's the point?

Comment: Additionally, I don't believe that `first[]` is a valid ID in HTML.

Comment: I know, i mentioned it. How do you advise me to send ID? If i send it in values with values, so after i should split them to get them separately, but I want to use more clever way.

Comment: @u_mulder they are not same

Comment: If you want the `id`, then add it to the name array -> `name="first[first]"`/`name="first[second]"`/`name="first[third]"` or `name="first[1]"`/`name="first[2]"`/`name="first[3]"`. Then you can get it in your loop -> `foreach($_POST['first'] as $id => $value){ echo 'ID: '.$id.' VALUE: '.$value.'<br/>'; }`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus u r right, i fixed ID part. `<input type="hidden">` is not good idea, cus id is coming from DB and automaticaly inserted in loop.

Comment: @Sean thank you very much, it was exactly what  i need, so u can answer to question and i will mark it as right answer)

Comment: @Orik0 So make the loop create `<input type="hidden">`. Do you have access to modify the loop code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get an `id` value from an input, used the `id` as key in your name array

```
<input type="checkbox" name="first[first]" .../>
<input type="checkbox" name="first[second]" .../>
<input type="checkbox" name="first[third]" .../>
```

or

```
<input type="checkbox" name="first[1]" .../>
<input type="checkbox" name="first[2]" .../>
<input type="checkbox" name="first[3]" .../>
```

then when you loop over your posted inputs, include the `key` in the `key=>value`

```
foreach($_POST['first'] as $id => $value){ 
    echo 'ID: '.$id.' => VALUE: '.$value.'<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  first<input type="checkbox" name="first[0][value]" id="first[]" value="first" />
  <input type="hidden" name="first[0][id]" value="first[]">
  second<input type="checkbox" name="first[1][value]" id="second[]" value="second" />
  <input type="hidden" name="first[1][id]" value="second[]">
  third<input type="checkbox" name="first[2][value]" id="third[]" value="third" />
  <input type="hidden" name="first[2][id]" value="third[]">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

And on the back-end:

```
foreach($_POST['first'] as $value){
  echo 'VALUE: '.$value['value'].'<br/>';
  echo 'ID: '.$value['id'].'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Now i catch what you mean) This one is also working for me!) Thank you !)

Comment: @Orik0 You're welcome. I honestly hope that you do not use my example in your project because this should be used only as a last resort but I do hope I was able to show you something new with regards to arrays in HTML/PHP. Good luck!

Comment: I used different way, but your way is something new for me, thankx for showing new ways!)